# Return value prop of component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties, components

Right now I have a component:

```
 <Icon name='close' value={ tag } onClick={ this.deleteTag.bind(this) } />
```

And an `onClick` event:

```
  deleteTag = (event) => {

      const tag = event.currentTarget.value; //returns undefined

  }
```

Is there a way I can return the `value` prop of my `Icon` component? My attempt as shown above would not work...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you have Icon Component from?

Comment: `this.deleteTag.bind(this, tag)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Icon` itself, does not have a value.. It's not an `input`

What you could do, is the following:

```
<Icon name='close' value={ tag } onClick={ () => this.deleteTag(tag) } />
```

Now the `tag` should be available in your `deleteTag` method.

Comment: I've never seen the `{ () => someMethod() }` syntax before.. could you let me know what it is called so I can look into it more? thanks again!

Comment: @user1547174 this is a short-style **arrow-function** (ES6). Its actually the same like `() => {}` or `function() {}` If the function budy is a single expression, you can use the short style

More Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions